# Deriving the stress-energy tensor from the Einstein-Hilbert action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, mathematics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, action

I'm a mathematician who knows very little physics and is trying to learn relativity theory from a mathematical perspective.

Let $M$ be a compact, orientable manifold. In the vacuum, the Einstein-Hilbert functional is
 \begin{equation}
  S(g) = \frac{1}{2\kappa} \int_M R_g \, v_g
 \end{equation}
 where $g$ is any semi-Riemannian metric on $M$ and we denote by $R_g$ and $v_g$ the scalar curvature  and volume form of $g$ respectively, 
 and $\kappa = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4} = 8\pi$ is a constant. The Euler-Lagrange equation for this functional is the Einstein equation $\mathrm{Ric}_g -\frac{1}{2} R_g \, g= 0$. I understand this and know how to prove it, so far so good.

What about the non vacuum case? From what I understand from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action), the presence of matter is encoded by a smooth function $\mathcal{L}_g  = \mathcal{L}(g, \cdot) \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$. In this case the functional is
  \begin{equation}
  S(g) =  \int_M \left[ \frac{1}{2\kappa}(R_g - 2\Lambda) + \mathcal{L}_g \right] \, v_g~.
 \end{equation}
Now, they say, the Euler-Lagrange equation is
 \begin{equation}
  \mathrm{Ric}_g -\frac{1}{2} R_g \, g= \kappa T
 \end{equation}
 where $$T := -2 \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}_g}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}} + \mathcal{L}_g g_{\mu \nu}$$ is the stress-energy tensor (by definition).

I am puzzled by this because:

1. For starters, it looks like the stress-energy tensor $T$ does not only depend on $g$, but also on its first variation $\delta g$. Therefore the Einstein equation is not properly speaking an equation on $g$. Isn't that unacceptable?

**Edit:** I mean, my understanding from the vacuum case is that Einstein's equation is an equation where the unknown is the metric $g$, and 
$g$ solving the equation is equivalent to being a critical point of the EH functional. Now this interpretation fails. Am I supposed to understand that now a solution is a $1$-parameter family of metrics? What would the parameter represent? (I thought that "time" is already part of $M$).

2. What is $\mathcal{L}$ supposed to be, say in terms of a mass distribution or something? I mean, if we say nothing about $\mathcal{L}$ other than it's a function of both $g$ and $x\in M$, that's the most general thing we can imagine to integrate. We might as well throw $\frac{1}{2\kappa}(R_g - 2\Lambda) $ in $\mathcal{L}$ then, why not? It seems a little silly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the first point. The Einstein field equation simply follows from setting $\delta S / \delta g_{\mu\nu} = 0$. Other equations of motion follow from setting $\delta S / \delta \phi = 0$ where $\phi$ stands for a matter field. All of these equations collectively determine the evolution of $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\phi$.

Comment: For the second point: that is an exceptionally, ah, mathematical way of learning relativity. I am frankly amazed that you got this far without having any idea what $\mathcal{L}$ would look like! Obviously you cannot get anywhere if you just imagine $\mathcal{L}$ as a completely general function. That's on the level of showing up to a programming job and describing the code you'll write as a general string of letters. Descriptions of what $\mathcal{L}$ is can be found in just about any physics textbook whatsoever and is determined by experimental measurement.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks for the comments. I edited my question to address your first point. As I wrote, I'm learning this for the first time so you can't expect me to know anything such as what's the Lagrangian in general relativity in the presence of mass, sorry if this is too basic.

Comment: For your first point — $T$ definitely does not depend on the variation of $g$: the expression $\delta\mathcal{L}_g/\delta g$ is a functional derivative completely independent of $\delta g$. As for your second point, the “matter Lagrangian” $\mathcal{L}_g$ typically only depends on $g$, not on its derivatives, as well as extra “matter” fields $\Phi$, for which the equations of motion plus the Einstein equations completely determine the evolution of the system (on a globally hyperbolic spacetime, that is).

Comment: Seub which textbook/source are you following to learn GR?

Comment: @magma: I'm using a little bit of O'Neill's "semi-Riemannian geometry" but he doesn't discuss this, and I glance stuff on the internet. I'm currently a TA in a math course called GR. But we don't really have the pretense to learn any physics, it's mostly a pretext to learn some math inspired by physics.

Comment: I see, I will write an answer soon